# Commit some oracle changes in transactionscope immediately?

Tags: c#, oracle, transactions, transactionscope

I have the following code:

```
using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
{
   try
   {
       OracleConnection _transactionDB = new OracleConnection("ConnectionString");
       _transactionDB.Open();

       OracleCommand _command = new OracleCommand();
       _command.Connection = _transactionDB;
       _command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       _command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (id, text) VALUES (3, 'test')";
       int rowsAffected = _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

       OracleCommand _command2 = new OracleCommand();
       _command2.Connection = _transactionDB;
       _command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       _command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO log (id, text) VALUES (3, 'Success')";
       int rowsAffected2 = _command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

       //...some other actions(DB changes)
   }
}
```

Is there a solution to commit the second insert immediately, doesn't matter if the transactionscope fails or not? This insert should always be visible in the database, to easier see what was going on in this transaction.

In oracle there is a 'AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION Pragma', which is like the function I need, in C#.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Looks like you use the Microsoft Data Provider for Oracle. This provider has been deprecated for long time. Better use Data Provider from Oracle, however I do not know if this support TransactionScope. In order to be on the safe side use method `BeginTransaction()` and `Commit()` resp. `Rollback()`. Of course you have to re-arrange your Oracle commands using several `try{} catch {}` blocks

Comment: Good point! Thanks I will take a look at the Data Provider from Oracle

Comment: Another approach is to clone the Oracle connection and use this clone for inserting log entries. This is actually almost the same what Oracle does in an Autonomous Transaction.

Comment: So when I clone a oracle connection, then the second connection is also in the TransactionScope and didn't get committed if transaction fails or?

Comment: Maybe "clone" was the wrong expression, simply open a new connection to the DB. The session do not interfere each other, it is like having two SQL*Plus windows open.

Comment: In my situation I use a distributed transaction(Read/Delete a message of a WebSphere MQ -> write message in DB -> if everything ok: commit).. I think if I make a seconds DB connection and execute a query in the transaction, the commit also depends on the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will solve you problem:

Write a Oracle PL/SQL Procedure to write the log. This procedure must have the pragma "AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION". Then call this procedure instead of inserting directly.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that, but not my preferred solution to call a PL/SQL Procedure many times.

Comment: Sometimes it is better to have an "atomic" functionality in the database which you can call from everywhere you want. In my environment I've got Java and APEX programms working on an Oracle Database. To make sure, that all do the things in the same way, I often use Stored Procedures. The biggest advantage is, to have the business-logic at only one place!!! Good Luck!